# Joomla + CB (Community Builder) + Google Apps

Tags: joomla

I started wondering today if it would be possible to integrate Joomla+CB with Google apps.
If that would be possible we could have one great product!

The first thing that I would want to integrate is the logon-process, one login for Joomla+Google apps.
Then it would be great to have some Google apps modules:
- your latest e-mails
- your next calendar entries
- your google talk buddies online/offline
- your most recent docs and spreadsheets

Comment: this would be sweet, so sad that nobody could answer this question

Answer (score 0):

This question has too many sides to it.
I'll provide the answer to the logon process. There's an extension called [Ulti RPX](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/authentication-cloud-based/9038).
It has some bugs and I've had to make many small changes to get it working well for me, but you can easily understand it and change it to provide your users with the integrated logon that you desire.